# How to enable/disable sound from ToggleButton?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make it in my app where if a user goes to my settings activity he could click on a ToggleButton and turn off the in-app audio.I'm trying to use the compound button method to accomplishing this but from what I found is this,

```
soundnotify.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                // Sound Notifications is enabled
            } else {
                // Sound Notifications is disabled
            }
        }
    });
```

What exactly am I supposed to put into the // portion of the code? I found this off the android website but it doesn't exactly explain what I'm supposed to put here to enable/disable the sound from the ToggleButton.I already specified in the XML the OnClick,TextOff and TextON so I'm just asking what am I supposed to do in the Java?

Thank You

Comment: can you tell me how you playing your sound in-app? So that I can give you some hint to stop that sound.

Comment: you want device volume sound of and on????

Comment: @altaf I haven't uploaded sounds yet to my app but I just want to include the ability to have the user to have a choice in the Setting via a ToggleButton to turn off the sounds or leave it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
soundnotify.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                // Sound Notifications is enabled
                soundnotify.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
            } else {
                // Sound Notifications is disabled
                soundnotify.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dinesh,Thank you very much but am I supposed select final on the code?

Comment: no it's Im getting this error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable soundnotify inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: change your toggle button declaration before add final keyword like final ToggleButton soundnotify=(ToggleButton)findViewById(YourXMLid);

Comment: Ok that is the right way just making sure thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry about that here you go

Answer (score 0):

You can store a boolean variable in `SharedPreferences` and check it every time you want paly sound.